# stored procedure problems

Tags: mysql, sql, prepared-statement

What is the correct way to pass values into this Stored procedure, obviously I'm not doing it the right way, and is it safe to execute two statements in one procedure or should I make two separate ones?

---

```
DELIMITER $$

    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `drop_student`(IN section_id VARCHAR(20), IN student_id  VARCHAR(20))
    BEGIN

    SET @section_id=section_id;
    SET @student_id=student_id; 

    PREPARE STMT2 FROM 
    "DELETE FROM transcript
    WHERE STUDENT_ID = @student_id
    AND SECTION_ID = @section_id ";


    PREPARE STMT FROM 
    "DELETE FROM course
    WHERE STUDENT_ID = @student_id
    AND SECTION_ID = @section_id ";


    EXECUTE STMT2 USING @section_id,@student_id;

    EXECUTE STMT USING @section_id,@student_id;

    END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you are using `SQL Server` (*I see `sql server` tag*) in your code above? I guess it's `MySQL`. Do it like this

```
PREPARE STMT2 FROM  "DELETE FROM transcript  WHERE STUDENT_ID = ? AND 
                                                   SECTION_ID = ?";
EXECUTE STMT2 USING @student_id,  @section_id;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE STMT2;

-- same as STMT
```

**[SQL Syntax for Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)**

Comment: thanks that worked, i was sending the statements in wrong order.

Answer (score 1):

To call the procedure you would do:

CALL drop_student('foo','bar');

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing this?

```
EXEC STMT2 @section_id @student_id;

EXEC STMT @section_id @student_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use prepared statements here.  Indeed, you could even combine your two `DELETE` statements into a single one:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE drop_student (
  IN p_section_id VARCHAR(20),
  IN p_student_id VARCHAR(20)
)
DELETE transcript, course
FROM   transcript JOIN course USING (STUDENT_ID, SECTION_ID)
WHERE  STUDENT_ID = p_student_id AND SECTION_ID = p_section_id;
```

Furthermore, it looks like you may be trying to manually implement behaviour that is provided automatically by [foreign key constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) with the `ON DELETE CASCADE` option.